# username and email altogether login in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I am currently doing a project. In this I want that the user login either his email or username but stuck at this As I cannot do this. I want that If a user provide his email or his username and password he can logged into his panel. I am using laravel 5.3 default function. I am doing this in laravel 5.1 but cannot do this in 5.3. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by overriding [`login()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L29) method in `Auth\LoginController.php`. Just check if credentials are valid and do this:

```
return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
```

For example:

```
if (Hash::check($request->password, $passwordFromDB) && ($request->username == $usernameFromDB || $request->email == $emailFromDB)) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}

return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
```

Comment: If I add this it gives me error `FatalThrowableError in LoginController.php line 42:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)`

Comment: @JahidMahmud, you shouldn't just add it. You should override `login()` controller and add credentials check there. If these credentials are valid, only then you should execute `return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);`

Comment: But how can I do this? @AlexeyMezenin. I tried but it gives me only to login either email or username not both

Comment: @JahidMahmud, copy&paste `login()` method (link is in the answer) if you want to keep some standard functionality or create `login()` method in `Auth\LoginController.php`. Then do something like `if (Hash::check($request->password, $passwordFromDB) && ($request->username == $usernameFromDB || $request->email == $emailFromDB)) { return $this->sendLoginResponse($request); }`

Comment: No sir It gives me error. In laravel 5.3 all functionality in login lies on Authenticatesuser.php. Could I paste your code on this. @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: @JahidMahmud, well, I gave you an idea, you should just put your variables there and test. And no, you shouldn't change `AuthenticatesUser.php` trait since it's in `vendor` directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126824/discussion-between-jahid-mahmud-and-alexey-mezenin).